# How do you convert a date into its string counterpart (e.g. 2015-06-03 to June 3, 2015)?

Tags: php, datetime

Given that the date is requested from another page and is redirected to the current page:
The previous page passed the value

```
wdate_from = '2016-06-03';
```

```
$date_from = $_REQUEST['wdate_from'];
```

How would you convert it to string such that it would result to

```
June 3, 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get the job done!

```
$date=date_create($date_from);
echo date_format($date,"F d, Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know Month and Day part you can use `mktime()` function to get `time`. Using the `$time` to `date('M d, Y, $time)` to output desired result.

Or You can just use `strtotime` function directly.

Something like this.

```
echo date('M d, Y, strtotime($date_from));
```

Comment: Great! It'll really help!